# Using mknod on Ubuntu in c program

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, mknod

I am trying to make a c program where i am using mknod command like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>

char info[50];

main() {
    int fdr;
    int rc = mknod("testfile",'b',0);
    if(rc<0) {
        perror("Error in mnod");
    }
    fdr=open("testfile",O_RDONLY);
    read(fdr,info,50);
    printf("\n Received message=%s",info);
    printf("\n");
}
```

And do some stuff. It works well on Red Hat system, but fails on ubuntu giving error invalid argument.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. Please copy and paste the actual code you are using.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
char info[50];
main()
{
        int fdr;
        int rc = mknod("testfile",'b',0);
        if(rc<0)
        {
            perror("Error in mnod");
        }
        fdr=open("testfile",O_RDONLY);
        read(fdr,info,50);
        printf("\n Received message=%s",info);
        printf("\n");
}

Comment: You should probably edit this into your question, it's hard to read when it's squashed in a single line like that...

Answer (score 3):

`mknod` is deprecated; you should not be using it. If you want to create a FIFO, use the standard `mkfifo`. If you want to create an ordinary file, use `creat` or `open` with `O_CREAT`. Yes `mknod` can create device nodes, and on some systems might still be the way to do it, but on a modern Linux system you rely on the kernel and/or `udevd` to handle this.

Comment: hmm mkfifo("testfile",010666) ==> Fails saying Invalid Argument

Comment: `010666` is not a valid mode. The mode is `0666`.

Comment: The claim that `mknod` is deprecated is unsubstantiated. No signs of deprecation on the documentation page https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ . Also it does not make sense since `udevd` runs in user space and needs a way to create special files.

Answer (score 2):

> mknod("testfile",'b',0);

`'b'` is not a very sensible argument for mknod here. `mknod`'s argument should be a bitwise OR of a permissions mask (modified by umask) and `S_IFREG` (for a regular file) or `S_IFIFO` (for a FIFO). For example:

> mknod("textfile", S_IFREG | 0666, 0);

Comment: mknod("testfile",010666,0); this one works for the linux [ red hat ] but for ubuntu give same error.

Comment: @asb, also, what filesystem are you attempting this on?

Comment: @asb, try running your program under strace; post the exact line of strace output for the mknod call.

Comment: the output for strace is very big and m not sure which line shld i add here

Comment: The one that starts with `mknod` :) It should be near the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can create named PIPI using mknode function but it also user to create dev file so you have to specify which file you want to create with user permission and dev type is zero

Syntax:

```
mknode (const char* fileName, mode_t mode | S_IFIFO, (dev_t) 0)
```

For example:

```
  mknode("pipe1",0777 | S_IFIFO, (dev_t) 0)
```

You also use mkfifo API for create file it's PIPE specify, In that no need to specify which kind of file you want to create:

```
mkfifo()
```